# react navigation createMaterialTopTabNavigator swipeEnabled not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new in react-native. I am trying to create a navigation tab which can switch between different routes by tapping the route or swiping horizontally.

I am using createMaterialTopTabNavigator of react-navigation [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html)

I followed as per the docs but swipe is not working.

My navigation file :

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/home/HomeView';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/settings/SettingsView';

const TabScreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    lazy: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      inactiveTintColor: '#F8F8F8',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#633689',
      },
      labelStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: '#87B56A',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
      },
    },
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  TabScreen: {
    screen: TabScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#633689',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      title: 'TabExample',
    },
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

My Home Screen and Setting Screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    class SettingScreen extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>
              Setting
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SettingScreen;
```

I am using the following packages:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.2",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.5.4",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.4.1",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the documentation and realized that I missed adding Andriod implementations and even forgot to modify MainActivity.java.

Just read this page https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html and follow the guides to do changes in Andriod and IOS files.

Comment: The shared doc doesn't have anything on the changes needed to done on Android and iOS files. can you please verify. I am still experiencing this issue

Comment: Ok its the "To finalize installation of react-native-gesture-handler for Android" part of Getting Started guide (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html). NOTE: This needs to be done even if you are using React Native 0.60+

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? I am not understanding what you are trying to say?